# What, *specifically*, makes DataMapper more flexible than ActiveRecord?

Tags: php, database, orm, datamapper

I'm comparing [Doctrine 2 and Propel 1.5/1.6](http://bit.ly/dUXa4n), and I'm looking in to some of the patterns they use. Doctrine uses the DataMapper pattern, while Propel uses the ActiveRecord pattern. While I can see that DataMapper is *considerably* more complicated, I'd assume some design flexibility comes from this complication. So far, the only legitimate reason I've found to use DataMapper over ActiveRecord is that DataMapper is better in terms of the single responsibility principle -- because the database rows are not the actual objects being persisted, but with Propel that doesn't really concern me because it's generated code anyway.

So -- what makes DataMapper more flexible?

Comment: Does anyone promote flexibility as the reason to prefer DataMapper over ActiveRecord? I thought its chief (possibly only) advantage was the superior separation of concerns (as you mentioned), which becomes more important when you have complex mappings or when you want the database and object models to evolve independently.

Comment: @Jeff: The entire point of SRP though is to make a design more flexible -- to be able to change one of the functions of a program without breaking other functions. If you're saying DataMapper makes it easier to make the domain objects (in PHP) completely separate from the database, that's a point of flexibility. (i.e. you might want to post that as an answer)

Answer (score 4):

I've worked with both, new Propel and Doctrine2. What DataMapper (and I mean Doctrine2) makes adorable is that your domain objects are clean and simple, they don't extend irrelevant classes which add many irrelevant methods to your classes (violating SRP as you said).  They're just simple entities with a few properties and a few methods that are a part of your business layer. And that, of course, lets you write unit tests for them and reuse them in the future.

I wouldn't say DataMapper considerably more complicated. It is complicated if you write your own implementation of DataMapper, but Doctrine2 is way easier to use than propel (maybe except for setting it up, we do that only once anyway). It has an entity manager that manipulates any entities. You may have entity repositories for complex queries. And that's it.

And an entity is as simple as:

```
/**
 * Question
 *
 * @Entity
 */
class Question
{
    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     */
    private $title;

    public function getTitle() { return $this->title; }
    public function setTitle($title) { $this->title = $title; }

}
```

In Propel we would have 6 classes for that entity which would contain a lot of generated and often unused code.

What makes DataMapper more flexible? Simplicity that it provides.

Comment: "...is way easier to use than propel..." <-- On what grounds? Learning an entirely new programming language (DQL) seems a hell of a lot harder than anything I've see propel do.... Oh, and you've really got a bad comparison here, because while the entity is simpler, you have to worry about proxy objects, query caches, the "EntityManager", etc., all of which are required to persist this entity, but none of which are in your example code. You've also not included the annotations required to make this object persistable. (In other words, that's an awfully biased comparison you've got here...)

Comment: Oh, and Propel is 3 classes per entity: `EntityName`, `EntityNamePeer` (which is deprecated), and `EntityNameQuery`.

Comment: @Billy ONeal If you know SQL, you know DQL. DQL syntax is very similar to SQL, all I needed to learn is how joins work. I don't have to worry about proxy objects and query caches - doctrine generates them for me, in memory  or in file - i don't need to care.  The entity manager is also 'ready-to-use', only needs to be configured (and i mentioned that). I haven't included annotations because the map of an object can be placed also in xml, yaml or php. Propel needs the map for an object too, so there's nothing realy to compare. But i updated the answer and included all required annotations.

Comment: And are the Base* classes in Propel gone?

Comment: @meze: If I wanted to write something like SQL, then why bother using an ORM of any description in the first place? I.e. if I'm still writing something that's essentially SQL, why not just write SQL queries? Not positive on the Base* classes thing.. I'll play and let you know. (Sorry if I sound argumentative here -- I'm playing devil's advocate because I've still not seen a *specific* case which makes DataMapper better than ActiveRecord)

Comment: @Billy ONeal I'm not trying to compare two different ORMs. My point is that DataMapper's entities are clean and know nothing about the fact that they're persistent, therefore they're very simple.
DQL is Doctrine's part and not related to the datamapper. Why DQL? Well, it's sort of an abstaction: in SQL you deal with tables, in DQL with objects. There are many widely used examples in other languages: HQL, LINQ, even FBQL. ps: so 6 classes per entity? i understand they're all auto generated but what i don't get is for 20 entites we'd have 120 classes... it's no good ;s

Comment: @meze: The difference between DQL and LINQ is that LINQ can be checked at compile time or by an editor. DQL will simply explode at runtime. For that matter, most all of Doctrine's API is "stringly typed" which strikes me as a code smell. W.r.t. size, the size argument doesn't sell me. For one thing, I don't see why having a lot of classes is a bad thing. For another, [the generated code is actually useful for something if your editor supports code completion](http://propel.posterous.com/video-ide-autocompletion-with-propel).

Comment: @meze: Really, there are 4 classes per database table. There's the EntityName and EntityNameBase classes, which are the active record itself. The EntityNameBase class is the generated class, and the non Base version lets you attach domain specific code to the entity so it isn't clobbered if/when the schema changes and the code is regenerated. There's also the EntityNameQuery and EntityNameQueryBase classes, (the reason for the Base is the same), which is used for more complicated queries between different entities. The other two, the *Peer and *PeerBase classes, are deprecated.

Comment: Oh, +1 by the way for taking the time to expound in these comments :)

Comment: As I've said, I don't 100% agree with this post, but nobody else seems to want to comment. So have a checkmark :)

Comment: "The difference between DQL and LINQ is that LINQ can be checked at compile time or by an editor. DQL will simply explode at runtime." <- Firstly, DQL is more like HQL, not like LINQ. Secondly, everything in PHP explodes at runtime.

Comment: @romanb the LINQ has SQL-like syntax, the argument was "why i need to learn dql". So I gave a few examples that SQL-like syntax is widely implemented in different languages and noone complains "i don't want to learn a new 'language'" (because they're helpful and almost identical to SQL). DQL is a higher level of abstraction that makes you think about objects and their relations, not about the tables. Yes, DQL will simply explode at runtime. So will SQL.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveRecord makes a data type do two things -- own responsibility for persisting data to a database, and own responsibility for storing the data for general calculations. This means that if you want to change the data store to which data is persisted in the future, code which generally doesn't have to care about database behavior is exposed to the change.

DataMapper completely decouples a given database implementation from a set of in-memory working objects, meaning the same internal working data type can be persisted to multiple databases, without modifying code that otherwise uses the working type.

For example, with DataMapper patterns, if tomorrow you want to add XML export for your data, you implement one new data mapper, the "MyDataToXmlDataMapper" or similar, that adds the new persistence format, and no other code has to change. With ActiveRecord adding such functionality requires changing the interface of the working data type.